# Method to detect the event when the e-mail ‘send’ button is pressed in Corona SDK

Tags: email, coronasdk

I need to detect the event when the the e-mail `send` button is pressed in one of my Corona application. I was referring from [Composing E-mail and SMS](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/01/03/composing-email-and-sms-in-corona/) (Posted on January 3, 2012. Written by Jonathan Beebe). But can not able to find any such methods.

The action is something similar to:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
 didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

of `Objective-C`.

**Edit:** I'm adding a sample image too:

[image]
Any help is appreciable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your valuable replies. As per my research and your answers, I concluded that there is no way to detect the mail `send/cancel` action in corona SDK till now. What I've to achieve is that: if the person pressed `send` button, the scene should be changed, else he/she must stay on the same page (for further edit).

So, I have done a trick to achieve this. What I done is:

- Created a `Custom Alert`.
- Called the Alert with a small delay when I trigger  `native.showPopup()`, so this alert will come under the e-mail popup.
- While you press `send/cancel mail`, the alert will be shown and it will ask the person either they have `send` the mail or `cancelled`.

  - YES = Scene change
  - NO  = Stay on same scene.

Hope this may help others who are fighting with the same problem...

Keep Coding......... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using native.showPopup() I don't believe there is a way to detect if the send button or cancel button was pressed back in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a 'Corona Staff', please inform your team that the developers need an apt solution for this problem. If you guys can make it work, then it will be a great help for developers like us. Thanks once again... :)

Comment: We add return handlers when they are available. We are sometimes limited by what the OS API we are calling allows us to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
local button = display.newImage( "namehere" )

function touchHandler( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        -- Do stuff here --
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
        event.target.isFocus=true
    elseif event.target.isFocus == true then
        if event.phase == "moved" then
            if inBounds( event ) then
                -- Do stuff here --
            else
                -- Do stuff here --
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
                event.target.isFocus=false
            end
        elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            -- Do stuff here --
            -- Send mail here
            -- Send mail here
            -- Send mail here
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
            event.target.isFocus=false
        end
    end
end

button:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the suggestion. But what do you mean by adding a new button..? I am saying about the native e-mail send button.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean? Are you seeking for native alerts? What do you want to achieve at all ^^ ?

Comment: To bad only twitter has a listener to the options, I think email didn't have it.

Comment: I think so, too.. I guess native library handles it and thats why it doesn't give the developer that event information

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the posts. I've achieved my need. Thanks for the support... :)